# Android Studio gradle errors

Tags: android, gradle

When i go to :

> File > Project Structure

I have the following 5 errors:

```
Library 'appcompat-v7-19.0.1' is not used
Library 'Gradle: 19.0.1' is not used
Library 'Gradle: support-v4-19.0.1' is not used
Library 'Gradle: 4.2.42' is not used
Library 'play-services-4.2.42' is not used
```

I can fix the problem with the icon on the right, add to dependencies and i add to the selected module, it works but if i exit Android Studio and i run it again, the errors appears again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors are spurious and you can ignore them; that they appear at all is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60958. Having said that, unless you're running a very old version of Android Studio, they shouldn't be appearing.